# How does jquery ready function allow it's first parameter to become jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today I stumbled upon this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($$){
    console.log($$);
});
```

Apparently, `$$` is considered as the `jQuery` object itself. Usually to do such a thing, we need to pass the `jQuery` variable:

```
(function($$){
    console.log($$);
}(jQuery))
```

But in case of ready function how does it know `$$` is the `jQuery` object? I think jquery defines the  ready function under the hood in a way that passes it's first parameter as `jQuery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described [in the docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

In this situation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($$){
    console.log($$);
});
```

- When the jQuery script tag runs, `window.jQuery` has jQuery assigned to it
- `jQuery(document)` references that global identifier
- jQuery.ready`'s callback, as designed, **calls its callback with the jQuery object**

This functionality doesn't have much use unless you're using `jQuery.noConflict`, but for another example of something similar:

```js
theLibrary().ready(function($$){
    console.log($$.libraryProp);
});
```

```html
<script>
// library example
window.theLibrary = Object.assign(
  // the library is both a function
  () => ({
    ready: (callback) => {
      callback(window.theLibrary);
    }
  }),
  // and an object with properties
  {
    libraryProp: 'libraryProp'
  }
);
</script>
```